# Is it allowed to use milk of a non-Indian breed cows in my vrata?

Tags: cows, vrata

There are several vratas in Hinduism that involves cow milk.

If I want to do a vrat that needs cow milk then is it mandatory that I need to use the milk of a cow that is of Indian breed?

Now-a-days there is a lot of availability of milk from cows of non-indian breeds such as jersey. Am I allowed to use them for performing my vrat?

Comment: I don't think it will be addressed in scriptures but I may be wrong

Comment: better to take milk from local gaushala that usually protects native breeds. one such [goshala](https://www.kinchit.org/goshala/)