# Are only Indian cows sacred?

Tags: cows

Scriptures seem to indicate all cows irrespective of their species to be sacred but I have heard about some traditionalists' claims that only Indian cows are sacred.

Is there any scriptural support of their claims?

---

Although it appears in Vaiśeṣika Sūtra-s that hump is a sine-quo-non condition for a cattle for being a cow, it might also mean that the Sutra has written so owing to the availability of such only cows in the past?

> VS-2.1.8. That it has horns, a hump, a tail hairy at the extremity,
> and a dewlap such is the admitted mark of being a cow.

Also, the sutra seems to indicate something else if we go by the context therein. i.e, the object of attention isn't the cow in the Sutra.

Comment: Do you have any source to back this claim? Looks quite strange. Even being not much of a scholar, I can definitely say we can't find this in scriptures as India wasn't formed at that time. So, whoever is saying is creating their own version of Hinduism.

Comment: @Mr_Green I remember great analyst Rajiv Dixit ji used to say this.

Comment: @Mr_Green it's coming from a scholarly authority. He claims that Yajña can't be performed with pañça gavya from non Indian cows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "cow" a concept or does it refer to just one species of milk-producing bovine animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/is-cow-a-concept-or-does-it-refer-to-just-one-species-of-milk-producing-bovine)

Comment: Related: [Is it allowed to use milk of a non-Indian breed cows in my vrata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40957/is-it-allowed-to-use-milk-of-a-non-indian-breed-cows-in-my-vrata)

Comment: @Mr.Sigma, I have heard this as well. Apparently there is a nadi (nerve) going through ear of Indian breed cows that doesn't exist in others. Also, the type of milk native Indian breeds produce is 'A2', as opposed to Jersey cows' A1. It is supposed to be healthier and is now marketed in Western nations also.